# Is this a valid proof that the set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with one element in. There is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ to
the set of all these: $f (x) = \{x\}$.
So the subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ with one element in it is uncountable. Because the set of all finite
subsets contains all these one-element subsets and more, it is uncountable. QED.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks good. (For this to work, you do need to know that a set with an uncountable subset is itself uncountable, but that's easy to prove --- and chances are you've already proved it.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the proof is okay.

I'd phrase the last sentence a bit differently, though: The set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb R$ is a superset of the set of all the singletons of $\Bbb R$, and the superset of an uncountable set is uncountable we have that the set of all finite subsets of $\Bbb R$ is uncountable.

(And a minor point for improvement, in case that you are using "the set of finite subsets of $\Bbb R$" often enough, it is worth adding a notation for it, e.g. $\operatorname{Fin}(\Bbb R)$.)

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. As WillO said you need to know that if $X$ has an infinite uncountable subset then it is uncountable. A way of seeing this is using the order of the cardinal numbers. If there exists an injective function from $Y$ to $Z$ then $Z$ is bigger(not strictly) than $Y$ hence any subset of $X$ is smaller(again, not strictly) than $X$.